# "ORDER BY" clause vs "INNER JOIN On MAX with GROUP BY"

Tags: sql-server, database, database-performance

As I am interested in NAME column which is updated recently. DATE_CREATED is also updated when there is change row data for that NAME.

I am not able to understand the performance impact of these two queries.
Both return the same result.

```
SELECT  E.NAME
    FROM EMPLOYEE E
        INNER JOIN (SELECT NAME, MAX(DATE_CREATED) DATE_CREATED
        FROM EMPLOYEE  WHERE E.NAME =  'XYZ' GROUP BY NAME ) E1
        ON E.DATE_CREATED =  E1.DATE_CREATED AND E.NAME =  E1.NAME 
    WHERE E.NAME =  'XYZ'
```

And

```
SELECT DATE_CREATED, NAME
    FROM EMPLOYEE 
    WHERE NAME = 'XYZ'
    ORDER BY DATE_CREATED DESC
```

Is sorting takes too much time compare to top query?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the execution plans? If you put both queries in the same window in SSMS and hit `Ctrl+L` the server will tell you which is more expensive *based on the indexes and statistics of the tables*.

Comment: The queries are completely different, so any comparison is meaningless. The second one will always be faster because it doesn't try to group or find max values but that doesn't mean much when the results are so different

Comment: I need NAME only from latest updated record

Comment: In that case the second query needs a `TOP 1`

Comment: It works but not for all types of DB